# input/output error when activating lenovo ideapad conservation mode

Tags: linux, drivers, lenovo-laptop

I've been very happy with Lenovo's conservation mode on my Yoga c940. But this time when I went to activate it I got the following error:

```
[kyle@leibniz ~]$ sudoedit /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004\:00/conservation_mode 
sudoedit: unable to write to /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode: Input/output error
sudoedit: contents of edit session left in /var/tmp/conservation_mode.XX0nhtvi
```

I am on Manjaro, following the [instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Lenovo_Yoga_c940) available on the ArchWiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's not working on 5.12, I have same problem with my Lenovo 14IIL05. I'm on arch and I installed `linux-lts` (which is 5.10 currently) and it works on that one all right.

Comment: This appears to have been resolved now. https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213109

Comment: can confirm 5.11 works as well

Comment: also works on 5.13

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem on Lenovo G580 linux 5.12.2 openSUSE tumbleweed

Also, I found [another solution](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Lenovo_IdeaPad_5_14are05#Battery_Conservation) on Arch wiki via acpi calls. But it didnt work for me too `Error: AE_NOT_FOUND`

So, I booted into ubuntu 20.10 with 5.8.0 kernel and successfully writen `0` to `/sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode`

Comment: So you're saying you booted with a different OS and were able to write to the file from there? Did that make it so you could edit the file again in Tumbleweed?

Comment: I'ts not like it is a real file, its just how linux presents this features. It seams to be broken in kernel 5.12, for me it works on 5.10 (archlinux lts kernel)